# Grouping in MySQL view scanning all partitions

Tags: mysql, view

I want to create a view in MySQL to allow data analysis users to easily filter large amounts of data, but when I create a view that has any grouping, the entire view is scanned making the view useless in terms of performance.

A simple example

Values Table - ca 3.5 billion rows, partitioned per month

```
SELECT
    Timestamp,
    DeviceId,
    SUM(Entry)
    FROM Value v
    WHERE DeviceId = 123456 AND Timestamp >= '2020-08-01'AND Timestamp <= '2020-08-30'
    GROUP BY Timestamp, DeviceId;
```

Using EXPLAIN I can see that the query scans the August partition and returns its values in 63ms using the primary key of (DeviceId,Timestamp), select type being 'SIMPLE'

When I create a view of this, omitting the WHERE clause, the EXPLAIN command shows that when using

```
SELECT * FROM vTest WHERE deviceid = 123456 AND Timestamp >= '2020-08-01'AND Timestamp <= '2020-08-30'
```

All partitions are scanned, the select type is DERIVED and the primary key is identified as a possible key, but not used. This makes the query take "forever".

If I create a view without grouping, this problem does not occur and the view uses the correct indexes/keys for scanning the underlying table.

Is it possible to use grouping in a view and 'pass the where clause to the underlying table' or will the user of the view always need to perform the grouping themselves.

GCP managed MySQL 5.7.25

Comment: When you say view do you mean VIEW as in create view...

Comment: Yes - as in CREATE VIEW vTest AS
SELECT
    Timestamp,
    DeviceId,
    SUM(Entry)
    FROM Value v
    GROUP BY  Timestamp, DeviceId;

Comment: Yeah, views are not particularly great in mysql. Any reason for using a view over a simple query?

Comment: The above example is just as simple as I could make it. The real views that will be created will combine data from multiple tables so as to only expose a standardised subset of the data rather than the entire database so that the users creating reports based on this data do not need to know the intricacies of the base database structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql can use [two algorithms](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html) to process a view:

> For MERGE, the text of a statement that refers to the view and the
> view definition are merged such that parts of the view definition
> replace corresponding parts of the statement.
>
> For TEMPTABLE, the results from the view are retrieved into a
> temporary table, which then is used to execute the statement.
>
> For UNDEFINED, MySQL chooses which algorithm to use. It prefers MERGE
> over TEMPTABLE if possible, because MERGE is usually more efficient
> and because a view cannot be updatable if a temporary table is used.

As per [restrictions on views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-restrictions.html) section of mysql manual:

> Indexes can be used for views processed using the merge algorithm. However, a view that is processed with the temptable algorithm is unable to take advantage of indexes on its underlying tables (although indexes can be used during generation of the temporary tables).

The select statement used for creating the view contains a `group by` clause. As per section [8.2.2.4 Optimizing Derived Tables, View References, and Common Table Expressions with Merging or Materialization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html) of the mysql manual:

> Constructs that prevent merging are the same for derived tables,
> common table expressions, and view references:
>
> Aggregate functions or window functions (SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), COUNT(),
> and so forth)
>
> DISTINCT
>
> GROUP BY
>
> HAVING
>
> LIMIT
>
> UNION or UNION ALL
>
> Subqueries in the select list
>
> Assignments to user variables
>
> Refererences only to literal values (in this case, there is no
> underlying table)

Because of the `group by` clause the `temptable` algorithm is used for the view. This results in mysql materialising the view as a temporary table first without pushing down the filter criteria from the outer query, resulting in the wider scan you see in the explain. The filtering happens on the temporary table and cannot take advantage of the indexes on the underlying tables.

You really need to be aware if mysql uses the merge or temptable approach for a view, since the behaviour of the views will very much depend on this choice.